# After merging two Dataframes how to filter the resulting one on two conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe of common information among users composed by:

```
user class
A    X
B    Y
C    Z
D    Y
E    Y
F    X
```

and another Dataframe of their activity composed by:

```
fing fer
A    B
A    E
B    D
B    C
B    F
C    A
D    E
E    B
F    D
```

The question is:

How many users that have a certain class are `fer` of other users that have another class?

For example, if the question is: how many users of class `X` are `fer` of users of class `Y`, the result should be: `3` because there are just `A, F` that have a class `X` and their relations are:

```
find fer
A    B
A    E
F    D
```

---

I have tried for now the following:

```
fing_table = pd_ci.merge(pd_f, how="right", left_on="user", right_on="fing")
fing_table.dropna(inplace=True)
fer_table = pd_ci.merge(pd_f, how="right", left_on="user", right_on="fer")
fer_table.dropna(inplace=True)
fs = fing_table.merge(fer_table, how="right", left_on="fing", right_on="fer").drop_duplicates(keep="first")

res = fs[fs["class"] == category_to and fs["class"] == category_from]
return res["user_x"].count()
```

But, it crashes because since it is a `Series` it would need either the `a.any()` or `a.all()` etc. inside the `and`-condition on `res`.

Avoiding the usage of an explicit for, how may I solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: `df2.assign(Class=df2['fing'].map(df1.set_index('user')['class'])).query("Class=='X'")` ?

Comment: So, I should not merge the 2 Dataframes?

Comment: umm , does that work for you? yeah you can  , map and merge pretty much work similar here

Comment: Ok, I just don't understand to which corresponds your `df2` and `df1` in my example.

Comment: `common information among users` as `df1` and `their activity ` as `df2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just write the solution of the problem: I solve the problem by using the piece of code proposed by @anky that is:

```
def fs_from_class_to_class(
    pd_ci: pd.DataFrame,
    pd_f: pd.DataFrame,
    class_from: str,
    class_to: str
) -> int:
   pd_f = pd_f.assign(fing_class=pd_f["fing"].map(pd_ci.set_index("user")["class"]))\
           .assign(fer_class=pd_f["fer"].map(pd_ci.set_index("user")["class"]))
   counter = pd_f.loc[(pd_f["fer_class"] == class_from) & (pd_f["fing_class"] == class_to)]
   counter = counter["fing"].count()
   return counter
```

Thank you for the answer!